# View with arguments

Tags: views, javascript

Can I build a view with parameters for the app? for example:
articles by author and articles that WILL show only the registered user ..
Is there an example of module done or I have to build only sight and go.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing out the lack of documentation on **Page Arguments** for DrupalGap. I went ahead and added a clear example of page arguments here: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Pages/Page_Arguments

A combination of `page_arguments` and a [Views Render Array](http://localhost/daux.io/Views/Displaying_a_View/Views_Render_Array) will get the job done.